# load data infile in mysql server 5.5 can't load data when foreign key exist

Tags: mysql-5.5, foreign-key

I have a database (TPC-DS benchmark base) with 24 tables(17 dimensions tables, 7 facts tables)
I generated this database then I created it in mysql server 5.5

I used the instruction load data local infile it works only when the table have not a foreign key, but tables with foreign key don't work and I can't find a solution to this error
here an example of a table and the error:

This is table without foreign key:

```
create table date_dim
(
    d_date_sk                 integer               not null,
    d_date_id                 char(16)              not null,
    d_date                    date                          ,
    d_month_seq               integer                       ,
    d_week_seq                integer                       ,
    d_quarter_seq             integer                       ,
    d_year                    integer                       ,
    d_dow                     integer                       ,
    d_moy                     integer                       ,
    d_dom                     integer                       ,
    d_qoy                     integer                       ,
    d_fy_year                 integer                       ,
    d_fy_quarter_seq          integer                       ,
    d_fy_week_seq             integer                       ,
    d_day_name                char(9)                       ,
    d_quarter_name            char(6)                       ,
    d_holiday                 char(1)                       ,
    d_weekend                 char(1)                       ,
    d_following_holiday       char(1)                       ,
    d_first_dom               integer                       ,
    d_last_dom                integer                       ,
    d_same_day_ly             integer                       ,
    d_same_day_lq             integer                       ,
    d_current_day             char(1)                       ,
    d_current_week            char(1)                       ,
    d_current_month           char(1)                       ,
    d_current_quarter         char(1)                       ,
    d_current_year            char(1)                       ,
    primary key (d_date_sk)
);
```

This is the table with foreign key:

```
create table web_site
(
    web_site_sk               integer               not null,
    web_site_id               char(16)              not null,
    web_rec_start_date        date                          ,
    web_rec_end_date          date                          ,
    web_name                  varchar(50)                   ,
    web_open_date_sk          integer                       ,
    web_close_date_sk         integer                       ,
    web_class                 varchar(50)                   ,
    web_manager               varchar(40)                   ,
    web_mkt_id                integer                       ,
    web_mkt_class             varchar(50)                   ,
    web_mkt_desc              varchar(100)                  ,
    web_market_manager        varchar(40)                   ,
    web_company_id            integer                       ,
    web_company_name          char(50)                      ,
    web_street_number         char(10)                      ,
    web_street_name           varchar(60)                   ,
    web_street_type           char(15)                      ,
    web_suite_number          char(10)                      ,
    web_city                  varchar(60)                   ,
    web_county                varchar(30)                   ,
    web_state                 char(2)                       ,
    web_zip                   char(10)                      ,
    web_country               varchar(20)                   ,
    web_gmt_offset            decimal(5,2)                  ,
    web_tax_percentage        decimal(5,2)                  ,
    primary key (web_site_sk)

CONSTRAINT web_d1 FOREIGN KEY (web_close_date_sk) REFERENCES date_dim (d_date_sk)
CONSTRAINT web_d2 FOREIGN KEY (web_open_date_sk) REFERENCES date_dim (d_date_sk)

);
```

Here are some of the data from the table date_dim:

```
2415022|AAAAAAAAOKJNECAA|1900-01-02|0|1|1|1900|1|1|2|1|1900|1|1|Monday|1900Q1|N|N|Y|2415021|2415020|2414657|2414930|N|N|N|N|N|
2415023|AAAAAAAAPKJNECAA|1900-01-03|0|1|1|1900|2|1|3|1|1900|1|1|Tuesday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414658|2414931|N|N|N|N|N|
2415024|AAAAAAAAALJNECAA|1900-01-04|0|1|1|1900|3|1|4|1|1900|1|1|Wednesday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414659|2414932|N|N|N|N|N|
2415025|AAAAAAAABLJNECAA|1900-01-05|0|1|1|1900|4|1|5|1|1900|1|1|Thursday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414660|2414933|N|N|N|N|N|
2415026|AAAAAAAACLJNECAA|1900-01-06|0|1|1|1900|5|1|6|1|1900|1|1|Friday|1900Q1|N|Y|N|2415021|2415020|2414661|2414934|N|N|N|N|N|
2415027|AAAAAAAADLJNECAA|1900-01-07|0|1|1|1900|6|1|7|1|1900|1|1|Saturday|1900Q1|N|Y|N|2415021|2415020|2414662|2414935|N|N|N|N|N|
2415028|AAAAAAAAELJNECAA|1900-01-08|0|1|1|1900|0|1|8|1|1900|1|1|Sunday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414663|2414936|N|N|N|N|N|
2415029|AAAAAAAAFLJNECAA|1900-01-09|0|2|1|1900|1|1|9|1|1900|1|2|Monday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414664|2414937|N|N|N|N|N|
2415030|AAAAAAAAGLJNECAA|1900-01-10|0|2|1|1900|2|1|10|1|1900|1|2|Tuesday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414665|2414938|N|N|N|N|N|
2415031|AAAAAAAAHLJNECAA|1900-01-11|0|2|1|1900|3|1|11|1|1900|1|2|Wednesday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414666|2414939|N|N|N|N|N|
2415032|AAAAAAAAILJNECAA|1900-01-12|0|2|1|1900|4|1|12|1|1900|1|2|Thursday|1900Q1|N|N|N|2415021|2415020|2414667|2414940|N|N|N|N|N|
2415033|AAAAAAAAJLJNECAA|1900-01-13|0|2|1|1900|5|1|13|1|1900|1|2|Friday|1900Q1|N|Y|N|2415021|2415020|2414668|2414941|N|N|N|N|N|
```

Data from table web_site

```
1|AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA|1997-08-16||site_0|2450807||Unknown|Ronald Shaffer|4|Grey lines ought to result indeed centres. Tod|Well similar decisions used to keep hardly democratic, personal priorities.|Joe George|6|cally|51|Dogwood Sunset|Ln|Suite 330|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.10|
2|AAAAAAAACAAAAAAA|1997-08-16|2000-08-15|site_0|2450798|2447148|Unknown|Tommy Jones|6|Completely excellent things ought to pro|Lucky passengers know. Red details will not hang alive, international s|David Myers|4|ese|358|Ridge Wilson|Cir.|Suite 150|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.00|
3|AAAAAAAACAAAAAAA|2000-08-16||site_0|2450798|2447148|Unknown|Tommy Jones|3|Completely excellent things ought to pro|Particular, common seasons shall not indicate fully more single decisions; |David Myers|4|ese|753|7th |Pkwy|Suite 210|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.02|
4|AAAAAAAAEAAAAAAA|1997-08-16|1999-08-16|site_0|2450781|2448956|Unknown|Harold Wilson|5|As strong notes deal questions. Proud visito|Deeply small books cannot extend all similar, clear historians. Free, new camp|James Harris|5|anti|805|Hill Hill|Dr.|Suite R|Midway|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.08|
5|AAAAAAAAEAAAAAAA|1999-08-17|2001-08-15|site_0|2450781|2448956|Unknown|Harold Wilson|5|Wide, final representat|Deeply small books cannot extend all similar, clear historians. Free, new camp|Edward George|1|ought|805|2nd 3rd|Road|Suite R|Fairview|Williamson County|TN|31904|United States|-5|0.08|
```

This is the error:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/Bureau/TPC-DS/tools/web_site.dat' INTO TABLE web_site FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tpcds`.`web_site`, CONSTRAINT `web_d1` FOREIGN KEY (`web_close_date_sk`) REFERENCES `date_dim` (`d_date_sk`))
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer was posted in the comments by the Question's owner. No further action needs to be taken

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs, when you are trying to insert or update a data instance to a foreign key data field in child table, which is not exist in the parent table.

You can solve this issue by **inserting the required values to the parent table before trying to insert it into the child table.**

Specifically, you must insert values to the **parent table** data field **d_date_sk** before loading values to **child table** data field **web_close_date_sk**. Or you must load the values to **web_close_date_sk**, which is already exists in **d_date_sk**. I hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: As well as doing what Rathish says, you could remove the FK constraints from your table definition, load **all** of your data and then add your FKs (example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)).

Comment: Thanks for all,  this problem is resolved: first I disabled  the constraint of foreign key, then load the data and finally  enable the foreign key  like this:                                                                                                set foreign_key_checks=0;                                                              LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/Bureau/TPC-DS/tools/web_site.dat' INTO TABLE web_site FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';  set foreign_key_checks=1;